# What does the PBO buffer content mean?

Tags: java, opengl, pbo

I was trying to implement a color picking system by using a PBO(pixel buffer object using OpenGL), and when I finished, I realized the numbers that came out of the PBO when mapped didn't make any sense at all. I made my application render big squares of different colors and the result **DID** change between these different colors, but even after analyzing the numbers, I can't make sense of it.

For example, clicking on pure red gave me bytes of
(-1,0,0), while pure blue gave (0,0,-1), but against all logic, pure green gives (-1,0,-1), cyan also gives (-1,0,0), and yellow gives (76,-1,0).

Obviously these numbers are wrong, given that two different colors can result in the same byte formation. Shouldn't a fully red color be (127,0,0)?

Here is the code I used for initialization, size 3 because I am only reading one pixel.

```
pboid = glGenBuffersARB(); //Initialize buffer for pbo
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, pboid); //bind buffer
glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, 3,GL_DYNAMIC_READ); //create a pbo with 3 slots
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, 0); //unbind buffer
```

And here is the code I used for reading the pixels

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, pboid); //Bind the pbo
glReadPixels((int)lastMousePosition.x,(int)lastMousePosition.y,1,1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); //Read 1 pixel
ByteBuffer colorBuffer = glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB); //Map the buffer so we can read it
for(int x = 0; x < colorBuffer.limit(); x++)
{
    System.out.println("color byte: " + colorBuffer.get(x)); //Print out the color byte
}
glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT); //Unmap the buffer so it can be used again
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_EXT, 0); //Unbind the pbo
```

If I am wrong in any assumptions I have made, please correct me. I am planning perhaps to use this system to tell which gui element is being clicked by rendering each of them to an fbo with a unique color and testing which pixel color was clicked on. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Comment: I sent a few ideas.  Also if you found my answer helpful, you may consider accepting the answer by clicking on the "tick' below the upvote/downvote arrows to the left of the answer :-). Doing this encourages responder's to help - but you are not obliged to accept

Comment: Does `glReadPixels` generate a GL error? Are you sure your colours should be there at the position of reading and not drawn later between reading and buffer swapping? Can you e.g. read from front buffer? -1 values appears correct, as you requested unsigned byte from GL, but java have only signed byte (but there should be functions to convert it to unsigned int).

Comment: My guess is that you forgot to transform the mouse coordinates from default window system conventions (origin at top left) to GL conventions (origin at bottom left). Furthermore, as already pointed out in the answer, printing unsigned values as signed will result in some confusion. But I have further questions: Why are you using stone-old ARB and EXT extensions? That stuff is in core GL since a decade by now. But it is also a moot point, because: why are you using a PBO at all? THe way you use it, it will only add a gigantic overhead, and you still force a full CPU-GPU synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At long last I have finally found the issue!

Firstly, using Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte), you can turn the color that the pbo gives you into your traditional 0-255 range rgb numbers.

Secondly, this being the primary issue, when OpenGL asks for pixel coordinates to fill a pbo, it is relative to bottom right. My issue was that I was using GLFW which gives coordinates relative to top right, meaning color picking in the vertical middle of the screen was accurate, but that it was getting the inverse part of the screen I was looking for when color picking elsewhere. To fix this, simply subtract the mouse click's y coordinate from the window height.

Thanks for the help and ideas!

Comment: Especially look at comments on the VBO and the ARB extensions

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities, but I don't have my openGL system set up to test - but you can try these anyhow. Also I don't know Java too well ( C,C++ etc is my domain)

**EDIT**

1) You have asked for `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` data from `glReadPixels()`, but you are printing out in signed format. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` has values 0-256, so negative values are not possible! Try to format you printout for `UNSIGNED_BYTE` and see where that leads.  (from your code I can see this is now fixed).

2) As derhass pointed out in his comments, you should not be using the ARB (architecture Review Board) extension versions of OpenGL buffer functions since these are part of OpenGL core for quite a long time now. See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/History_of_OpenGL for version history. From this I can see glBindBufferARB (for example) was deprecated in 2003. It may or not impact your particular problem, but replace glXXXXXARB() with glXXXXX() thorughout, and make sure your OpenGL libraries are recent (v4 or later).

3) Also credit derhass, and reading your GitHub code, your `getMousePosition()` via glfwGetCursorPos returns screen coordinates (0,0 is top left of your window) so you need to convert to viewport coordinates (0,0 is bottom left) to read the framebuffer. Your code at GitHub seems not to be making the conversion.

4) Also credit derhass, you dont' need to use PBO at all for basic color picking.  glReadPixels() default target is the framebuffer, so you can safely dispense with the VBO and get color, depth and stencil data directly from the framebuffer. (you need to enable the depth and stencil buffers).

5) If you are selecting on a 3D scene, you will also need to convert (unproject) the viewport coordinates and depth back to worldcoordinates to be able to identify which object you have clicked on. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection for some ideas on selection.

I hope all this helps a bit, although it feels a like learning experience for both of us.

Comment: With PBO bound last argument of glReadPixels becomes offset in buffer, not a pointer, much like glVertexAttribPointer takes offset in VBO if VBO is bound.

Comment: @keltar Ah did not know this - been a while..  Where is this documented?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_pixel_buffer_object.txt fourth paragraph of overview section.

Comment: Point 1 was already disproven by others, and as for point 3, the buffer is not null, Java would give a NullPointerException if it was, and I am getting data from it through methods.

Comment: Point 2, however provided some insight to me. I know that java does not support unsigned bytes (or really anything unsigned for that matter, excluding the primitive type 'char'). There are, however, some convenience functions to convert a signed byte to an integer so as to provide a positive result that you would expect. I used them and some of the numbers I got seemed about right, but still, many seemed quite wrong. I have a transparent black background in a spot that gave reasonable numbers when clicked (very low color values), but some of the same colored squares give different results.

Comment: Well we are looking for clues.... The infallible strategy I use 1) is to make the smallest possible program that reproduces the problem 2) KNOW that it WILL work if you get everything right. Also check <https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes> because that also speak of packing issues with glGetPixels. Sometimes debugging is pure persistence remembering point 2).

Comment: Interesting, some of the same colored square give different results. Aka two different red squares give different colors from the buffer even though they are quite obviously the same color. I would say that my location must be wrong, but the color inside an entire square remains constant and the color within the entire transparent box remains low. Any insight guys? Here is what I am rendering to the screen: https://imgur.com/KQThQ6q

Comment: I read what was said about the GL_RGB, and it said to use GL_RGBA, which I have complied with, making my buffer size 4 instead. The alpha value always appears to be correct, but I am still having issues with the same colored blocks not being the correct color when read with glReadPixels. You mentioned creating a simpler project and trying to isolate the problem. Would it be helpful if I created a github project showcasing the issue? Also, should I create a new question in this case, since my question will have changed to, 'Why is glReadPixels giving partially wrong information'?

Comment: @PoisonedPorkchop I think you might be right that locations are somehow not what you expect. I would try to move across the screen in 1 pixel increments and see what pattern emerges. You may find an offset that makes sense. Otherwise for sure post your code to Github and send a link. Its 7PM here is Australia so its red wine time . .. and I will be off air for a day or so.

Comment: A note on number 4, I intend to render a scene but make the objects color completely a unqiue color (in a different fbo), so that when I find a color at a certain pixel, I know that the color belongs to that object, and therefore can use it to send a click to the correct place every time. In the link you provided me, the method I am going for is the last one on the More Techniques list. Therefore I do plan to use a different fbo. As for the pbo, I have read that it is purely an efficiency to use one, and not required, though many sources complain that the efficiency isn't much higher.

Comment: Great go for it. The inefficiency I suppose is drawing everything twice, once with normal textures and then with the unique color per object. That MIGHT matter on a commercial game, where most of the commentary on openGL comes from. But its a clever method and seems much less complicated than other methods. Send me a message when all working!

Comment: I have implemented it, after some messing about with framebuffers as I hadn't used one before. It works surprisingly well, and I am quite satisfied with how responsive it is. As for rendering the scene twice, I only update render when there is a change in the scene, such as a gui moving. Considering I am only using this method for guis, and guis don't often move much, other than a one off click to move and then its done, the performance impact is small. Anything clicked that is not a gui is black, so I have the opportunity to use a different object picking system for in world objects.